# How to sort strings correctly starting with special characters (such as İ,ı,Ç,ç,Ğ,ğ,ş,ö,ü...) in PrimeFaces dataTables?

Tags: java, hibernate

We are using PrimeFaces 2.2 (w/JSF 2.x in a Java EE 5 project) and we are having trouble in correctly sorting strings starting with special characters (e.g. İstanbul, Çankaya, Ödemiş...) in PrimeFaces dataTables although we are using UTF-8.

The problem is that words starting with special characters are put at the end of the words starting with Z, whereas, for example, a city name starting with "İ" (i.e. İstanbul) should normally show up between Ibiza and Jacksonville, rather it ends up appearing after Zurich. This rule is based on the Turkish (tr_TR)  locale.

In selectOneMenus however the sorting is performed correctly (and as desired above)

Any suggestions for a workaround would be greatly appreciated.

**_ EDIT _**

This issue relates to hibernate (hsql) based sort, not a sql based sort

Comment: Did you find any workaround for this issue? I have been experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This should help a bit, here everything get converted to basic uppercase/lowercase chars before the sort

```
select k from test order by convert(k using utf8_bin)
```

Comment: Is there a way of testing this in Hibernate without having to execute a native SQL query?

Comment: The simples approach should be a custom comparator and doing Collection.sort on your results. The down side to this the sort is done in java not on the database level

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sort properly unless you know the language sorting order for the words. And if the words are mixed language, there is no correct sorting order however in that case people usually use the language sorting order for the majority of the users/audience.

The exact same characters with the exact same sounds and the exact same Unicode code points, will sort in different places depending on the language and even the country.

Here is the definition of the Unicode collation algorithm http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/

Comment: The language is Turkish, locale is set to 'tr-TR' and the sorting is done correctly in selectOneMenu / f:selectItems on the same page, however p:dataTable fails to sort correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Locale-aware collation is a tricky business, and therefore probably best dealt with dedicated libraries. I'd suggest using [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/). I cannot provide any details on how to integrate that with the hsql workflow, so I'd probably try to sort things separately if that is an option.